# Generate manifest files for registration-free COM

Tags: com, manifest, dll, regfreecom, typelib

I have some applications (some native, some .NET) which use manifest files so that they can be [deployed in complete isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h.aspx), without requiring any global COM registration. For example, the dependency on the dbgrid32.ocx com server is declared as follows in the myapp.exe.manifest file which sits in the same folder as myapp.exe:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="myapp.exe" version="1.2.3.4" />
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="dbgrid32.ocx" version="5.1.81.4" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

The dbgrid32.ocx is deployed to the same folder, along with it's own dbgrid32.ocx.manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="dbgrid32.ocx" version="5.1.81.4" />
  <file name="dbgrid32.ocx">
     <typelib
        tlbid="{00028C01-0000-0000-0000-000000000046}"
        version="1.0"
        helpdir=""/>
    <comClass progid="MSDBGrid.DBGrid"
       clsid="{00028C00-0000-0000-0000-000000000046}"
       description="DBGrid  Control" />
  </file>
</assembly>
```

This all works fine but maintaining these manifest files manually is a bit of a pain. Is there a way to generate these files automatically? Ideally I would just like to declare the application's dependency on a list of COM servers (both native and .NET) and then let the rest be generated automatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It looks like the perfect solution does not yet exist. To summarize some research:

**Make My Manifest** ([link](http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/))

This tool scans a VB6 project to look for COM dependencies, but it also supports manual declaration of late-bound COM dependencies (i.e. those used via CreateObject).

Interestingly enough, this tool puts all information about the dependencies inside the application manifest. The application exe and its dependencies are described as a single assembly consisting of multiple files. I hadn't realized before that this was possible.

Looks like a very good tool but as of version 0.6.6 it has the following limitations:

- only for VB6 applications, starts
  from VB6 project file. Shame, because
  a lot of what it does really has nothing to do
  with VB6.
- wizard style application, not
  suitable to integrate in a build
  process. This is not a huge problem if your
  dependencies don't change a lot.
- freeware without source, risky to rely on it because it could become abandonware at any moment.

I did not test whether it supports .NET com libraries.

**regsvr42** ([codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/regsvr42.aspx))

This command line tool generates manifest files for native COM libraries. It invokes DllRegisterServer and then spies on the self-registration as it adds information into the registry. It can also generate a client manifest for applications.

This utility does not support .NET COM libraries, since these don't expose a DllRegisterServer routine.

The utility is written in C++. The source code is available.

**mt.exe**

Part of the windows SDK (can be downloaded from [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4377f86d-c913-4b5c-b87e-ef72e5b4e065&displaylang=en)), which you already have if you have visual studio installed. It is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649.aspx).
You can generate manifest files for native COM libraries with it like this:

```
mt.exe -tlb:mycomlib.ocx -dll:mycomlib.ocx -out:mycomlib.ocx.manifest
```

You can generate manifest files for .NET COM libraries with it like this:

```
mt.exe -managedassemblyname:netlib.dll -nodependency -out:netlib.dll.manifest
```

However, there are some problems with this tool:

- The first snippet will not generate
  progid attributes, breaking clients
  which use CreateObject with progids.
- The second snippet will generate
  `<runtime>` and `<mvid>` elements
  which need to be stripped out before
  the manifests actually work.
- Generation of client manifests for
  applications is not supported.

Maybe future SDK releases will improve this tool, I tested the one in the Windows SDK 6.0a (vista).

Comment: I think you missed one option: http://www.mazecomputer.com/ but I know nothing about it the web site doesn't describe.

Comment: MMM will also redirect non-COM (standard) DLLs.  I'm not sure the other tools do this.

Comment: Just a note for the nervous: the source for MMM has been released. On the downside, this appears to be because the author has decided to stop working on it. Still a positive sign.

Comment: The site for MMM is nolonger up but the place where the source code was put is still available for [v0.9](https://app.box.com/s/4u0chwmyaw6xhuecekj4) and [v0.12](https://app.box.com/s/yvm0wk95e1lachm7juf5).

Comment: Just tried mt.exe for .NET COM libraries as described above and it worked with no modification to the manifest using v7.1A.
Also, the links for MMM didn't work but [Unattented Make My Manifest](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM) seems to do a decent job.

Answer (score 33):

With the MSBuild task [GenerateApplicationManifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wc2ccdc.aspx) I generated a manifest at the command line identical to the manifest Visual Studio generates.  I suspect Visual Studio uses the [GenerateApplicationManifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wc2ccdc.aspx) during the build.  Below is my build script which can be run from the command line using msbuild "msbuild build.xml"

Thanks to Dave Templin and his [post that pointed me the the GenerateApplicationManifest task](https://web.archive.org/web/20120810070249/http://windowsclient.net:80/Articles/ClickOnce_MsBuild.aspx), and MSDN's [further documentation of the task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wc2ccdc.aspx).

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <File Include='MyNativeApp.exe'/>
            <ComComponent Include='Com1.ocx;Com2.ocx'/>
        </ItemGroup>
        <GenerateApplicationManifest
            AssemblyName="MyNativeApp.exe"
            AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0"
            IsolatedComReferences="@(ComComponent)"
            Platform="x86"
            ManifestType="Native">
            <Output
                ItemName="ApplicationManifest"
                TaskParameter="OutputManifest"/>
        </GenerateApplicationManifest>
    </Target>   
</Project>
```

Comment: I think this should really be marked as the answer to this question. I am now using this to automate all of our manifest generation. Thank you @mcdon, you've saved me a lot of work.

Comment: I agree this is the best solution when building with Visual Studio.  It is probably not rated higher only because it was posted so much later than the other answers

Comment: how to add this into a csproj?

Comment: @jle I think you could add it to your csproj in the AfterBuild target.  Here's a [link from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx), and [another post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) on the topic of prebuild and postbuild events.  _Note_ I haven't tested including this in the csproj, but I suspect it would work.

Comment: Can the manifest be generated for a C# COM DLL, so that any exe can consume it (rather than generating a manifest on each exe, and including the DLLs?)

Comment: @GilesDMiddleton The manifest is specific to the exe. For the example above "MyNativeApp.exe" the manifest file created would be "MyNativeApp.exe.manifest". I don't think there is an equivalent at the dll level.

Comment: 11 years late to the party but thanks for the mention!

Comment: @DaveTemplin Thank you! Your article was a great help to me :)

Answer (score 9):

[Make My Manifest (MMM)](http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/) is a nice tool for doing this.  It's also possible to write a script to process all your DLL/OCX files using [mt.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649.aspx) to generate a manifest for each one and then merge them all together.  MMM is usually better/easier, because it also handles lots of special/weird cases.

Comment: I'm a bit nervous about this MMM thing; it's just a blog, freeware but no source code available, only a link to a "self-extracting exe" and I see comments about the utility causing XP to crash. mmm...

Comment: Those "crashes" were the MMM utility itself dying.  This was fixed in version 0.6.5 but you'll want 0.6.6 anyway, since while still a beta it no longer expires.

You can always use MT.EXE instead though as already suggested.

Comment: mt.exe is not generating progid's when I use it on native com servers like dbgrid32.ocx

Comment: Use of reg free COM with .NET authored components can apparently cause XP to crash - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617253/is-anyone-successfully-using-registration-free-com-with-net-components

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Unattended Make My Manifest](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM) spin off to generate manifests directly in automated builds. It uses a script file to add depended COM components. This is an excerpt from the sample ini with the available commands:

```
# Unattended MMM script
#
# Command names are case-insensitive. Reference of supported commands:
#
# Command: Identity
#
#   Appends assemblyIdentity and description tags.
#
#   Parameters       <exe_file> [name] [description]
#      exe_file      file name can be quoted if containing spaces. The containing folder 
#                    of the executable sets base path for relative file names
#      name          (optional) assembly name. Defaults to MyAssembly
#      description   (optional) description of assembly
#
# Command: Dependency
#
#   Appends dependency tag for referencing dependent assemblies like Common Controls 6.0, 
#     VC run-time or MFC
#
#   Parameters       {<lib_name>|<assembly_file>} [version] [/update]
#     lib_name       one of { comctl, vc90crt, vc90mfc }
#     assembly_file  file name of .NET DLL exporting COM classes
#     version        (optional) required assembly version. Multiple version of vc90crt can
#                    be required by a single manifest
#     /update        (optional) updates assembly_file assembly manifest. Spawns mt.exe
#
# Command: File
#
#   Appends file tag and collects information about coclasses and interfaces exposed by 
#     the referenced COM component typelib.
#
#   Parameters       <file_name> [interfaces]
#     file_name      file containing typelib. Can be relative to base path
#     interfaces     (optional) pipe (|) separated interfaces with or w/o leading 
#                    underscore
#
# Command: Interface
#
#   Appends comInterfaceExternalProxyStub tag for inter-thread marshaling of interfaces
#
#   Parameters       <file_name> <interfaces>
#     file_name      file containing typelib. Can be relative to base path
#     interfaces     pipe (|) separated interfaces with or w/o leading underscore
#
# Command: TrustInfo
#
#   Appends trustInfo tag for UAC user-rights elevation on Vista and above
#
#   Parameters       [level] [uiaccess]
#     level          (optional) one of { 1, 2, 3 } corresponding to { asInvoker, 
#                    highestAvailable, requireAdministrator }. Default is 1
#     uiaccess       (optional) true/false or 0/1. Allows application to gain access to 
#                    the protected system UI. Default is 0
#
# Command: DpiAware
#
#   Appends dpiAware tag for custom DPI aware applications
#
#   Parameters       [on_off]
#     on_off         (optional) true/false or 0/1. Default is 0
#
# Command: SupportedOS
#
#   Appends supportedOS tag
#
#   Parameters       <os_type>
#     os_type        one of { vista, win7 }. Multiple OSes can be supported by a single 
#                    manifest
#
```

It will run on 32 or 64 bit Windows.

Comment: +1 Interesting, especially because the source code is available. I'm a bit confused by the name similarity, apparently "make my manifest" and "unattended make my manifest" are different tools by different authors.

Comment: Note - as of 2017 (8 years on...) this project is still active with occasional maintenance updates. https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM/commits/master .  It works well and I use it routinely.

Answer (score 0):

To fill in the ProgIDs that mt.exe doesn't include, you can call `ProgIDFromCLSID` to look them up from the registry. This requires traditional COM registration prior to completing the manifest file, but subsequently, the manifest file will be self-sufficient.

This C# code adds the ProgIDs to all COM classes in a manifest:

```cs
var manifest = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("s", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");
foreach (var classElement in manifest.XPathSelectElements("s:assembly/s:file/s:comClass", namespaceManager)) {
    var clsid = Guid.Parse(classElement.Attribute("clsid").Value);
    int result = ProgIDFromCLSID(ref clsid, out string progId); if (result != S_OK) throw new COMException($"ProgID lookup failed for {clsid}.", result);
    classElement.SetAttributeValue("progid", progId);
}
manifest.Save(fileName);
```

The code relies on these interop definitions:

```cs
[DllImport("ole32.dll")] static extern int ProgIDFromCLSID([In] ref Guid clsid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string lplpszProgID);
const int S_OK = 0;
```

Comment: Recent versions of `mt.exe` do include the ProgIDs if you give the rgs file via `-rgs:`