# If I registered a TLB do I still need to register the ocx in order to compile?

Tags: build, vb6, ocx, typelib

I am trying to compile a vb6 application and I can't register the ocx files. In order to attempt to compile I have replaced the Object= lines in the .vbp file with Reference= lines to the TLB instead of the OCX.  Now when I compile I get the following type of errors.

```
Line 125: Class KimgpLib.KImgp of control KImgp1 was not a loaded control class.
Line 145: Class KFormLib.KForm of control KForm1 was not a loaded control class.
```

I have registered the tlb files using regtlib.exe but cannot register the ocx files.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why can't you register the OCX Files? If you can register TLB you should be able to do OCXs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to read up on reg free COM which also works with OCXs
You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com). The process involves creating manifest files for each library (DLL or OCX but not ActiveX EXE)