# VB6: what can I do to ensure my application uses specific versions of MS controls and DLLs?

Tags: vb6, dll

What can I do to ensure my application uses specific versions of MS controls and DLLs?

Can I put the correct versions of the DLLs and OCXs in the application directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include the COM components in your directory and use either DotLocal or Registration Free COM to force Windows to use them.

DotLocal is simpler, but still requires the COM components to be registered globally.  Registration Free COM means that you don't need to register your COM components globally at all, but it is more difficult to setup.

DotLocal requires Windows 2000 or later and Registration Free COM requires Windows XP or later.

Links for DotLocal:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682600

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/dotlocal-local-dll-redirection)

Links for Registration Free COM:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408052%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

[Generate manifest files for registration-free COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com)

Comment: Which out of DotLocal and Reg-Free COM is better?