# VB6 RegFreeCom SideBySide SxS Manifest Test for TABCTL32.ocx

Tags: vb6, manifest, side-by-side, regfreecom, sxs

In not so recent years, I have added Configuration forms to some of my VB6 programs. Tab controls are pretty handy to group different categories for the various configurations to be managed.

My Development PC is a virtual PC running Windows XP (32bit) Service Pack 3. I am programming with Visual Basic 6.0 (SP6).

It turns out that other user's PCs, not used for VB6 Programming Development and with newer versions of Windows, do not immediately understand what to do with this 'new fangled' Tab control.

tabctl32.ocx is an ActiveX control module which contains SSTab control used for Tabbed Dialog Control. Non-system processes like tabctl32.ocx originate from software you installed on your system.

[vb6 "regfreecom" autocreate manifest for ocx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667173/vb6-regfreecom-autocreate-manifest-for-ocx-file)

Recently, I was reminded that, in years past, I had worked out a process for dealing with this:

1. Create a tiny simple program with the purpose of exercising the Control in question.
2. Provide the Manifest and Resource files needed.
3. Compile, Build and Test the program.
4. Build and use the NSIS file to create the SxS installation file for testing on any target PCs.
5. With your original VB6 program, incorporate your new Manifest file and changes to its Resource file and proceed with its build and testing.

---

1. Create a tiny test simple program:

   - Open VB6 [New Standard EXE]
   - In the Project Properties list provide a Name: (e.g.: zTABCTL32)
   - Open the Toolbox
   - Project > Components > [Browse]: TABCTL32.ocx  [Open] [*OK*]
   - Click on an item just added to the bottom of the Toolbox (e.g.: SSTab)
   - Add an SSTab to the Form
   - In the Form Properties list provide a Name: (e.g.: frmTABCTL32)
   - In the Form Properties list provide a Caption: (e.g.: TABCTL32)
   - Save your form and project (maneuver to and/or create an appropriate folder)
   - Set Project zTABCTL32 Properties [General] > Startup Object: [Sub Main] > [*OK*]
   - Add to Project: main_zTABCTL32.bas - (Sub Main - frmTABCTL32.show)
   - Edit main_zTABCTL32.bas Sub Main() to make sure Correct Form Name is in .Show command
   - Add to Project: Module1.bas - (Declarations)
   - Add to Project: ReadWritePathFile.bas (Utilities for Read/Write Path/Files)
   - Add code to form (frmzTABCTL32)
   - Run [Start With Full Compile]

---

main_zTABCTL32.bas - Sub Main - frmzTABCTL32.show ...

---

```
Attribute VB_Name = "main_zTABCTL32"
Private Type InitCommonControlsExStruct
    lngSize As Long
    lngICC As Long
End Type
Private Declare Function InitCommonControls Lib "comctl32" () As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function InitCommonControlsEx Lib "comctl32.dll" (iccex As InitCommonControlsExStruct) As Boolean

Private Sub Main()

    Dim iccex As InitCommonControlsExStruct, hMod As Long
    Const ICC_ALL_CLASSES As Long = &HFDFF& ' combination of all known values
    ' constant descriptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775507%28VS.85%29.aspx

    With iccex
       .lngSize = LenB(iccex)
       .lngICC = ICC_ALL_CLASSES    ' you really should customize this value from the available constants
    End With
    On Error Resume Next ' error? Requires IEv3 or above
    hMod = LoadLibrary("shell32.dll")
    InitCommonControlsEx iccex
    If Err Then
        InitCommonControls ' try Win9x version
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    '... show your main form next (i.e., Form1.Show)
    frmTABCTL32.Show
    If hMod Then FreeLibrary hMod


'** Tip 1: Avoid using VB Frames when applying XP/Vista themes
'          In place of VB Frames, use pictureboxes instead.
'** Tip 2: Avoid using Graphical Style property of buttons, checkboxes and option buttons
'          Doing so will prevent them from being themed.

End Sub

'Sub Main()
'    frmTABCTL32.Show
'End Sub
```

---

Module1.bas - Form Resize and Icon Manipulations

---

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
'Re:Bonnie West +vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
Option Explicit

Public Const WINDOWS_ICON As Integer = 1
Public Const CHROME_ICON  As Integer = 2

Public Const HALF         As Single = 0.5!

Public Const ICON_JUMBO   As Long = 256

Public Const ICON_BIG     As Long = 1
Public Const ICON_SMALL   As Long = 0
Public Const WM_SETICON   As Long = &H80

Public Enum E_DrawIconEx_Flags
    DI_MASK = &H1
    DI_IMAGE = &H2
    DI_NORMAL = &H3
    DI_COMPAT = &H4
    DI_DEFAULTSIZE = &H8
    DI_NOMIRROR = &H10
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim DI_MASK, DI_IMAGE, DI_NORMAL, DI_COMPAT, DI_DEFAULTSIZE, DI_NOMIRROR
#End If

Public Enum E_GetWindowLong_Index
    GWL_USERDATA = (-21&)
    GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20&)
    GWL_STYLE = (-16&)
    GWL_ID = (-12&)
    GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8&)
    GWL_HINSTANCE = (-6&)
    GWL_WNDPROC = (-4&)
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim GWL_USERDATA, GWL_EXSTYLE, GWL_STYLE, GWL_ID, GWL_HWNDPARENT, GWL_HINSTANCE, GWL_WNDPROC
#End If

Public Enum E_LoadImage_Type
    IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
    IMAGE_ICON = 1
    IMAGE_CURSOR = 2
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim IMAGE_BITMAP, IMAGE_ICON, IMAGE_CURSOR
#End If

Public Enum E_LoadImage_fuLoad
    LR_DEFAULTCOLOR = &H0
    LR_MONOCHROME = &H1
    LR_LOADFROMFILE = &H10
    LR_LOADTRANSPARENT = &H20
    LR_DEFAULTSIZE = &H40
    LR_VGACOLOR = &H80
    LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS = &H1000
    LR_CREATEDIBSECTION = &H2000
    LR_SHARED = &H8000&
End Enum
#If False Then
    Dim LR_DEFAULTCOLOR, LR_MONOCHROME, LR_LOADFROMFILE, LR_LOADTRANSPARENT, _
    LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_VGACOLOR, LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION, LR_SHARED
#End If

Public Type RECT
    Left   As Long
    Top    As Long
    Right  As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Public Declare Function AdjustWindowRectEx Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByRef lpRect As RECT, _
    ByVal dwStyle As Long, _
    ByVal bMenu As Long, _
    ByVal dwExStyle As Long _
) As Long

Public Declare Function DrawIconEx Lib "user32.dll" ( _
             ByVal hDC As Long, _
             ByVal xLeft As Long, _
             ByVal yTop As Long, _
             ByVal hIcon As Long, _
    Optional ByVal cxWidth As Long, _
    Optional ByVal cyWidth As Long, _
    Optional ByVal istepIfAniCur As Long, _
    Optional ByVal hbrFlickerFreeDraw As Long, _
    Optional ByVal diFlags As E_DrawIconEx_Flags = DI_NORMAL _
) As Long

Public Declare Function GetWindowLongW Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As E_GetWindowLong_Index _
) As Long

Public Declare Function LoadImageW Lib "user32.dll" ( _
             ByVal hInst As Long, _
             ByVal lpszName As Long, _
    Optional ByVal uType As E_LoadImage_Type = IMAGE_BITMAP, _
    Optional ByVal cxDesired As Long, _
    Optional ByVal cyDesired As Long, _
    Optional ByVal fuLoad As E_LoadImage_fuLoad = LR_DEFAULTCOLOR _
) As Long

Public Declare Function SendMessageW Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal uMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long _
) As Long

'Private Sub Main()
'    MsgBox "Don't forget to set ""windows_perfection_logo_v2_d-bliss.ico"" as Form1's Icon!" & _
'            vbNewLine & "(Set it via the Properties Window)", vbInformation
'    Form1.Show
'    Form2.Show
'End Sub
'Re:Bonnie West +^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

ReadWritePathFile.bas (Utilities for Read/Write Path/Files)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public sOutputPath As String

'Function:  AssurePathExists
'Purpose:   If the complete specified path does not exist, then create it.
'Parms:     sPathName - String - The full path to be assured e.g.:
'               D:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3  or D:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\
'                   If the last character is not a "\", it will be supplied.
'Returns:   True if the path already exists or was successfully created, False if unsucessful.
Public Function AssurePathExists(ByVal sPathName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Exit_AssurePathExists
Dim sTestPath As String, iPos As Integer
    AssurePathExists = False
    If IsNumeric(sPathName) Then Exit Function
    If Len(sPathName) = 0 Then Exit Function
    If Right$(sPathName, 1) <> "\" Then sPathName = sPathName & "\"
    If PathExists(sPathName) Then
        AssurePathExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
        
    iPos = 0
    Do Until iPos = Len(sPathName)
        iPos = InStr(iPos + 1, sPathName, "\")
        sTestPath = Left$(sPathName, iPos)
        If Not PathExists(sTestPath) Then MkDir sTestPath
    Loop
    AssurePathExists = True
    
Exit_AssurePathExists:
    Exit Function
End Function


Function CloseFileOutput(ByVal iFileNumber As Integer) As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    Close #iFileNumber
    CloseFileOutput = 0
End Function


'
'Function:  ExtractPath
'Purpose:   extract and return the path part of a full pathname.
'Parms:     FullPathName - String containing the full path name of a file.
'Returns:   String containing the path part of the specified full path file name.
Function ExtractPath(ByVal FullPathName As Variant) As String
    Dim i As String

    'Preset the returned string to an empty string.
    ExtractPath = ""
    
    'Validate input parameter.
    If (VarType(FullPathName) <> vbString) Then Exit Function
    FullPathName = Trim(FullPathName)
    If (Len(FullPathName) = 0) Then Exit Function
    If (InStr(FullPathName, "\") = 0) Then Exit Function
    
    'Find the last "\" in the full path name.
    i = InStrRev(FullPathName, "\")
    
    'Return the path part of the specified full path name.
    ExtractPath = Left$(FullPathName, i - 1)
End Function



Function OpenFileOutput(ByVal sApp_Path_OutFile As String, Optional bAppend As Boolean = False) As Integer           '04apr2011
    On Error GoTo Err_OpenFileOutput
    OpenFileOutput = 0
    If Not PathExists(ExtractPath(sApp_Path_OutFile)) Then Exit Function            '30sep2011
    OpenFileOutput = FreeFile
    If bAppend Then
        Open sApp_Path_OutFile For Append As #OpenFileOutput
    Else
        Open sApp_Path_OutFile For Output As #OpenFileOutput
    End If
Exit_OpenFileOutput:
        Exit Function
Err_OpenFileOutput:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 70
                MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "File: " & sApp_Path_OutFile & " is already open" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "     OR  possibly ..." & vbCrLf & "Remove Redirection from command line e.g.:" & vbCrLf & "> " & sApp_Path_OutFile & vbCrLf & "Specify Output file path and name in _.INI file", , "OpenFileOutput "
                OpenFileOutput = 0
                Resume Exit_OpenFileOutput
            Case Else
                MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, , "Error in OpenFileOutput() "
                OpenFileOutput = 0
                Resume Exit_OpenFileOutput
        End Select
End Function


'
'Function:  PathExists
'Purpose:   Determine whether or not a pathname is valid.
'Parm:      pathname - String containing a file name or path to be tested.
'Returns:   True, if the path is valid.
'           False, if path is invalid.
Function PathExists(ByVal pathname As String) As Boolean
    Dim res As Variant 'RSF 6/17/98 Declared as Variant to accept a NULL value.
    
    PathExists = False
    
    If IsNumeric(pathname) Then Exit Function                   '29sep2011
    'If input pathname is empty, it's not a valid path
    If (Len(pathname) = 0) Then Exit Function
    
    'Check for valid path. invalid path causes trappable runtime error
    On Error GoTo patherror
    res = Dir(pathname, vbDirectory)
    
    'RSF 6/17/98 Dir can return a NULL, check for a string before proceeding.
    If (VarType(res) <> vbString) Then Exit Function
    
    'If length of the result is zero, it's not a valid path
    If (Len(res) = 0) Then Exit Function
    
    PathExists = True
    Exit Function
    
patherror:
End Function



Public Function SetgsRWApp_Path() As String
On Error Resume Next
Dim sAppPath0 As String, sAppSubFolder As String, sProgramFiles As String, sProgramFilesx86 As String, sProgramData As String, sPUBLIC As String
    
    SetgsRWApp_Path = ""
    sAppPath0 = App.Path
    sProgramFiles = Environ("ProgramFiles")
    sProgramFilesx86 = Environ("ProgramFiles(x86)")
    sProgramData = Environ("ProgramData")
    sPUBLIC = Environ("PUBLIC")

    If (Len(Trim(sPUBLIC)) > 0) Then
        sPUBLIC = Left(sAppPath0, 3) & Mid(sPUBLIC, 4)
    End If
    
    If Len(Trim(sProgramFilesx86)) > 0 Then
        sProgramFilesx86 = Left(sAppPath0, 3) & Mid(sProgramFilesx86, 4)        '28aug2017
        sAppSubFolder = Mid(sAppPath0, InStr(sAppPath0, sProgramFilesx86) + Len(sProgramFilesx86))
        If (Len(Trim(sPUBLIC)) > 0) And (InStr(sAppPath0, sProgramFilesx86) > 0) Then
            SetgsRWApp_Path = sPUBLIC & sAppSubFolder
        ElseIf (Len(Trim(sProgramData)) > 0) And (InStr(sAppPath0, sProgramFilesx86) > 0) Then
            SetgsRWApp_Path = sProgramData & sAppSubFolder
        Else
            MsgBox "Cannot create Read/Write Application Path" & vbCrLf & "sAppPath0='" & sAppPath0 & "'" & vbCrLf & "sProgramFiles='" & sProgramFiles & "'" & vbCrLf & "sProgramFilesx86='" & sProgramFilesx86 & "'" & vbCrLf & "sProgramData='" & sProgramData & "'" & vbCrLf & "sPUBLIC='" & sPUBLIC & "'", vbCritical, "SetgsRWApp_Path"
        End If
    ElseIf Len(Trim(sProgramFiles)) > 0 Then
        sProgramFiles = Left(sAppPath0, 3) & Mid(sProgramFiles, 4)        '28aug2017
        sAppSubFolder = Mid(sAppPath0, InStr(sAppPath0, sProgramFiles) + Len(sProgramFiles))
        If (Len(Trim(sPUBLIC)) > 0) And (InStr(sAppPath0, sProgramFiles) > 0) Then
            SetgsRWApp_Path = sPUBLIC & sAppSubFolder
        ElseIf (Len(Trim(sProgramData)) > 0) And (InStr(sAppPath0, sProgramFiles) > 0) Then
            SetgsRWApp_Path = sProgramData & sAppSubFolder
        Else
            SetgsRWApp_Path = sAppPath0
        End If
    Else
            MsgBox "Cannot create Read/Write Application Path" & vbCrLf & "sAppPath0='" & sAppPath0 & "'" & vbCrLf & "sProgramFiles='" & sProgramFiles & "'" & vbCrLf & "sProgramFilesx86='" & sProgramFilesx86 & "'" & vbCrLf & "sProgramData='" & sProgramData & "'" & vbCrLf & "sPUBLIC='" & sPUBLIC & "'", vbCritical, "SetgsRWApp_Path"
    End If
    
    
End Function



Sub WriteFileOutput(ByVal iFileNumber As Integer, ByVal strOutput As String)
    On Error GoTo Err_WriteFileOutput
    If iFileNumber > 0 Then
        Print #iFileNumber, strOutput
    End If
Exit_WriteFileOutput:
        Exit Sub
Err_WriteFileOutput:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case Else
                MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, , "WriteFileOutput"
                Resume Exit_WriteFileOutput
        End Select
End Sub
```

---

Add code to form (frmzTABCTL32)

---

```
Option Explicit     'Don't forget to set the "windows_perfection_logo_v2_d-bliss.ico" icon as the MDIForm's Icon! (Set it via the Properties Window)

Private Const pbID As String = "picIcon"

Private Declare Function DestroyIcon Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hIcon As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindowExW Lib "user32.dll" (Optional ByVal hWndParent As Long, Optional ByVal hWndChildAfter As Long, Optional ByVal lpszClass As Long, Optional ByVal lpszWindow As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function InvalidateRect Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, Optional ByVal lpRect As Long, Optional ByVal bErase As Long = -True) As Long

Private m_hIcon   As Long
Private m_hWndMC  As Long
Private m_picIcon As VB.PictureBox

Private Const lbID As String = "lblVerPathFile"
Private m_lblVPF As VB.Label
Private sCaption0 As String                                     'SSTab Test Code

Private Sub Form_Load()

    sOutputPath = SetgsRWApp_Path() & "\Data"

    AssurePathExists sOutputPath
'09jun2020 vvvvvvv
Dim strOutfile As String, iFileOutputNumber As Integer, bAppend As Boolean, strRecord As String
    strOutfile = sOutputPath & "\" & Me.Name & ".txt"
    bAppend = True
    strRecord = Me.Name & "   Form_Load() " & App.Path & "  " & strOutfile
    iFileOutputNumber = OpenFileOutput(strOutfile, bAppend)
    WriteFileOutput iFileOutputNumber, strRecord
    CloseFileOutput iFileOutputNumber
'09jun2020 ^^^^^^^
    Set m_lblVPF = Controls.Add("VB.Label", lbID)                   '03jun2020  vvv
    With m_lblVPF
        .Height = 615
        .Left = 240
        .Top = 120
        .Width = 4215
        .Caption = App.EXEName & "  " & App.Major & "." & Format(App.Minor, "00") & "." & Format(App.Revision, "0000") & vbCrLf & sOutputPath & "\" & vbCrLf & Me.Name & ".txt"
        .Visible = True
    End With                                                        '03jun2020  ^^^
    sCaption0 = m_lblVPF.Caption                                'SSTab Test Code

'Re:Bonnie West +vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    m_hWndMC = FindWindowExW(hWnd, , StrPtr("MDIClient"))

    If App.LogMode Then
        Set Icon = Nothing
        m_hIcon = LoadImageW(App.hInstance, WINDOWS_ICON, IMAGE_ICON, ICON_JUMBO, ICON_JUMBO)
        SendMessageW hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, LoadImageW(App.hInstance, WINDOWS_ICON, IMAGE_ICON, , , LR_DEFAULTSIZE)
        SendMessageW hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, LoadImageW(App.hInstance, WINDOWS_ICON, IMAGE_ICON, 16&, 16&)
    End If

    Set m_picIcon = Controls.Add("VB.PictureBox", pbID)
    With m_picIcon
        .AutoRedraw = True
        .BackColor = BackColor
        .BorderStyle = 0
        .ClipControls = False
        .ScaleMode = vbPixels
    End With
'Re:Bonnie West +^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Resize()

'Re:Bonnie West +vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    If WindowState <> vbMinimized Then
        With m_picIcon
            .Cls
            .Move 0!, 0!, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight

            If m_hIcon Then
                DrawIconEx .hDC, (.ScaleWidth - ICON_JUMBO) * HALF, _
                                 (.ScaleHeight - ICON_JUMBO) * HALF, m_hIcon, ICON_JUMBO, ICON_JUMBO
            ElseIf Not Icon Is Nothing Then
               .PaintPicture Icon, (.ScaleWidth - .ScaleX(Icon.Width, vbHimetric, vbPixels)) * HALF, _
                                   (.ScaleHeight - .ScaleY(Icon.Height, vbHimetric, vbPixels)) * HALF
            End If

            Set Picture = .Image
            InvalidateRect m_hWndMC
        End With
    End If
'Re:Bonnie West +^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strOutfile As String, iFileOutputNumber As Integer, bAppend As Boolean, strRecord As String
    strOutfile = sOutputPath & "\" & Me.Name & ".txt"
    bAppend = True
'08jun2020    strRecord = Me.Name & vbCrLf & App.EXEName & " " & App.Major & "." & Format(App.Minor, "00") & "." & Format(App.Revision, "0000") & vbCrLf & App.Path
    strRecord = Me.Name & "   " & Format(Now, "yyyy mmm dd hh:nn am/pm") & vbCrLf & App.EXEName & " " & App.Major & "." & Format(App.Minor, "00") & "." & Format(App.Revision, "0000") & vbCrLf & App.Path  '08jun2020
    iFileOutputNumber = OpenFileOutput(strOutfile, bAppend)
    WriteFileOutput iFileOutputNumber, strRecord
    CloseFileOutput iFileOutputNumber
    
    Set m_lblVPF = Nothing
    Controls.Remove lbID

'Re:Bonnie West +vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    Set m_picIcon = Nothing
    Controls.Remove pbID

    If m_hIcon Then
        DestroyIcon m_hIcon
        DestroyIcon SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, 0&)
        DestroyIcon SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, 0&)
    End If
'Re:Bonnie West +^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

End Sub



Private Sub SSTab1_Click(PreviousTab As Integer)

m_lblVPF.Caption = sCaption0 & " [ " & PreviousTab & " ] "      'SSTab Test Code

End Sub
```

---

2. Provide the Manifest and Resource files needed.

Shut Down VB6 zTABCTL32 Project **or** remove zTABCTL32.RES from Project

UMMM.ini

- This .ini file, following the Identity line, contains a list of
  dependency files. They are listed in the .vbp file (e.g.:
  `Object={BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}#1.1#0; TABCTL32.OCX`
  ).
- You can also find them itemized within VB6 Menu > Project >
  Components ...
- On that Components form, you can choose `[x] Selected Items Only` to
  more easily view the list.
- Highlighting each Component in the list will display, below: `(e.g.: Location C:\ ... \TABCTL32.OCX )`
- In the .ini file, I specify the path to the dependency file because
  it is not stored in the local Project folder.

---

```
Identity zTABCTL32.exe zTABCTL32.exe "TABCTL32 Test program 1.0"  
File C:\WINDOWS\system32\TABCTL32.ocx
```

---

UMMM.bat

---

```
UMMM.exe zUMMMTabCtl32.ini .\manifest\zTABCTL32.exe.manifest

pause done?
```

---

[Is there a way to specify File Name= in UMMM (Unattended Make My Manifest) creation of Program.exe.manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517902/is-there-a-way-to-specify-file-name-in-ummm-unattended-make-my-manifest-creat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

I edited the resulting `zTABCTL32.exe.manifest` with Notepad and changed:

From:  `<file name="..\..\..\..\WINDOWS\system32\TABCTL32.ocx">`
To:    `<file name="Dependencies\TABCTL32.ocx">`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity name="zTABCTL32.exe" processorArchitecture="X86" type="win32" version="1.0.0.20" />
    <description>TABCTL32 Test program 1.0</description>
    <file name="Dependencies\TABCTL32.ocx">
        <typelib tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" version="1.1" flags="control,hasdiskimage" helpdir="" />
        <comClass clsid="{BDC217C5-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" progid="TabDlg.SSTab.1" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,simpleframe,setclientsitefirst">
            <progid>TabDlg.SSTab</progid>
        </comClass>
        <comClass clsid="{942085FD-8AEE-465F-ADD7-5E7AA28F8C14}" tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,simpleframe,setclientsitefirst" />
    </file>
</assembly>
```

---

*MT.bat    - this did not work out for me?

My reference is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/mt-exe*

---

```
mt  -nologo -manifest .\manifest\zTABCTL32.exe.manifest -outputresource:"zTABCTL32.RES;1"

pause Done?
```

---

*The Resource file was not created? I have no idea what the [#] Resource_ID (1) is?*

---

```
C:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\zTABCTL32>mt  -nologo -manifest .\manifest\zTABCTL32.exe.ma
nifest -outputresource:"zTABCTL32.RES;1"

mt : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resourc
e of file "zTABCTL32.RES". The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\zTABCTL32>pause Done?
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

**Instead I used ManifestCreatorv2.0.3**

```
 - The Manifest > Create from Project File (vbp) zzTABCTL32.vbp
 - The Manifest > Append/Merge Manifest - From file [e.g.: .\manifest\zTABCTL32.exe.manifest]   
 - The Manifest > Export Manifest >
          [_] Indent Manifest
          [_] Do Not Use Prefixed Name Spaces
          [x] Do Not Export Empty/Blank Attributes
          Destination Resource File - save to zzTABCTL32.RES (Replace)    
 - Open VB6 zTABCTL32 Project or Add zTABCTL32.RES back into Project
```

---

---

3. Compile, Build and Test the program.

   - Within VB6 zTABCTL32 Project, start witn full compile: Runs OK
   - Within VB6 zTABCTL32 Project, File -> Make new executable:
   - Save Project

---

Running zTABCTL32.exe from with in its Project folder
[Run-Error 7 out of memory?]

---

4. Build and use the NSIS file to create the SxS installation file for testing on any target PCs.

```
I adjusted the NSIS file to install only the dependency files listed in the .vbp file, the UMMM.ini file and in the resulting .exe.manifest file.
```

---

**Installed on WinXP(32) works OK

Installed on Win7(64) works OK

Installed on Win10(64) works OK**

---

5. With your original VB6 program, incorporate your new Manifest file and changes to its Resource file and proceed with its build and testing.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: On my other ~posting I meandered between 2 questions. With this I am trying to build an organized resolution of 1 problem. I have run into a problem of a clear process for creating the zTABCTL32.exe.manifest. I tried mt.exe again. Even putting MSVCP100.dll in its folder, it complains about no MSVCR100.dll ?? I downloaded a copy of that, but NO!! After I get this finished, I plan to prune the other one out to focus on MSCOMCTL.ocx In hindsight, for Tab form controls TABCTL32.ocx seems to be a light weight compared to MSCOMCTL.ocx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using UMMM to generate a simple manifest for the SSTab control and it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity name="MyCompany.Project1" processorArchitecture="X86" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <description>MyCompany Project1 1.0</description>
    <file name="TABCTL32.ocx">
        <typelib tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" version="1.1" flags="control,hasdiskimage" helpdir="" />
        <comClass clsid="{BDC217C5-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" progid="TabDlg.SSTab.1" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,simpleframe,setclientsitefirst">
            <progid>TabDlg.SSTab</progid>
        </comClass>
    </file>
</assembly>
```

Check out the complete test project [here](https://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/SSTabManifest.zip). The `build.bat` in `scripts` shells `Ummm.exe` to generate `Project1.ini.manifest` and then uses `mt.exe` to embed this manifest in `Project1.exe` executable.

This batch file execution can be skipped altogether if the manifest is one-time compiled to a `RES` file and this `Project1.res` file is added to the VB6 project.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I made some progress. Previously, many of my most recent problems were around trying to include stdole2.tlb

Answer (score 0):

I have taken 2 of my programs through these steps, using `UMMM.exe` and  `ManifestCreatorv2.0.3` and `VB6` and an updated `NSIS file` to succesfully operate on all 3 systems:

**Installed on WinXP(32) works OK

Installed on Win7(64) works OK

Installed on Win10(64) works OK**

There are still some things I do not understand about UMMM.exe and MT.exe.
Additional understanding may help with a better answer.

Another conclusion from this experience is that there is NO need to create manifest files for individual dependency files.

If anyone is really curious, the 2 freeware programs I have fixed are Gastro and QueryMgr at https://www.indra.com/~anderci/ciaartcl.htm