# Is there a way to specify File Name= in UMMM (Unattended Make My Manifest) creation of Program.exe.manifest?

Tags: dependencies, vb6, manifest, sxs

Is there a way to adjust the UMMM.ini file and / or the UMMM.bat file to specify in the `<File Name=... >` the \Dependencies subdirectory when it creates the Program.exe.manifest?

Re: [vb6 "regfreecom" autocreate manifest for ocx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667173/vb6-regfreecom-autocreate-manifest-for-ocx-file)

Re: [VB6 RegFreeCom SideBySide SxS Manifest Test for TABCTL32.ocx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184019/vb6-regfreecom-sidebyside-sxs-manifest-test-for-tabctl32-ocx)

Using a UMMM.ini file like:

```
Identity zTABCTL32.exe zTABCTL32.exe "TABCTL32 Test program 1.0"  
File C:\WINDOWS\system32\TABCTL32.ocx
```

and a UMMM.bat file like:

```
UMMM.exe zUMMMTabCtl32.ini .\manifest\zTABCTL32.exe.manifest

pause done?
```

Then editing the resultant .exe manifest file:

From: `<file name="..\..\..\..\WINDOWS\system32\TABCTL32.ocx">`
To: `<file name="Dependencies\TABCTL32.ocx">`

---

YES the discussion in https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM/issues/16 is in the same ballpark.
I DID tweak the UMMM.vbp to redirect from `SysWOW64` to `System32`.
But that is as far as I want to go. Maybe if I am patient, they will work out a solution.

Here is the final Program.exe.manifest that works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity name="zTABCTL32.exe" processorArchitecture="X86" type="win32" version="1.0.0.20" />
    <description>TABCTL32 Test program 1.0</description>
    <file name="Dependencies\TABCTL32.ocx">
        <typelib tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" version="1.1" flags="control,hasdiskimage" helpdir="" />
        <comClass clsid="{BDC217C5-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" progid="TabDlg.SSTab.1" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,simpleframe,setclientsitefirst">
            <progid>TabDlg.SSTab</progid>
        </comClass>
        <comClass clsid="{942085FD-8AEE-465F-ADD7-5E7AA28F8C14}" tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,simpleframe,setclientsitefirst" />
    </file>
</assembly>
```

My efforts are on a tiny scale, not production.

---

### wqw, thank you for all of your efforts.

I am embarrassed to say I did not, at first, take your instructions literally enough.
**Here is the .ini file (That Works!):**

```
Identity zTABCTL32.exe zTABCTL32.exe "TABCTL32 Test program 1.0"  

File C:\WINDOWS\system32\TABCTL32.ocx "" "" Dependencies\TABCTL32.ocx
```

And here is the .bat file:

```
C:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\UMMM-master_1_0_14\UMMM.exe zUMMMTabCtl32.ini .\manifest\zTABCTL32.exe.manifest

pause done?
```

Here is the resulting manifest file in its appropriate folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity name="zTABCTL32.exe" processorArchitecture="X86" type="win32" version="1.0.0.23" />
    <description>TABCTL32 Test program 1.0</description>
    <file name="Dependencies\TABCTL32.ocx">
        <typelib tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" version="1.1" flags="control,hasdiskimage" helpdir="" />
        <comClass clsid="{BDC217C5-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" progid="TabDlg.SSTab.1" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,simpleframe,setclientsitefirst">
            <progid>TabDlg.SSTab</progid>
        </comClass>
        <comClass clsid="{942085FD-8AEE-465F-ADD7-5E7AA28F8C14}" tlbid="{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,simpleframe,setclientsitefirst" />
    </file>
</assembly>
```

**This does it all! Thank you.**

Comment: Can you add what you would LIKE the INI to look like, just as an example? Its a little hard to follow your question.

Answer (score 1):

@wqw provided the solution:

> I just added support for surrogate value for name attribute in commit
> [77c7e07](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM/commit/77c7e075c81eaf2fbd7e8158aaa41963d427a794). Use something like
>
> ```
> File UcsFP20.dll "" "" 
> Dependency\UcsFP20.dll
> ```
>
> to supply explicit value of `Dependency\UcsFP20.dll` for name
> attribute in final manifest. Version 1.0.14 can be downloaded from
> repo's Releases tab.

– wqw Jun 24 '20 at 16:52

This was also referred to in https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM/issues/16 which lead up to that commit.

Again, thank you.