# Can I "generate" COM visible assemblies?

Tags: c#, com

Can I generate COM visible assemblies (using CodeDom, or anything else) ?

I am looking to expose C# classes to VBA. Basically, I have an object-driven web server, and everytime I build my web server, I would like to also generate some wrapping classes (COM visible using CodeDom) as some clients will need these to access data from other contexts (Excel/VBA, etc...).

So is this possible at all ?

**UPDATE:**
Trying the **RegFree** approach of **Snoopy**, I build that class into test2.dll with CodeDom:

```
   namespace Test
   { 
       public class TestClass
       {
        private double _d1;
        private double _d2;

              public double d1 {
                get { 
                  return _d1; }
                set { _d1 = value; }
              }

           public double d2 {
            get { return _d2; }
            set { _d2 = value; }
           }

           public double sum()
           {
            return d1 + d2;
           }
       }
   }
```

I get the following in VBE:
[image]

Comment: It just takes attributes, so no problem.

Comment: I am puzzled by the COM registration aspect. My understanding is that the attribute would not be dealing with that.

Comment: I assume the ComVisible attribute is handled by compiler magic, so this is why i think it will only work with registerless com, but i am not 100% sure, so feel free to correct me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using Register Free COM.

1)Open Excel and add the following references

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoree.tlb (Common Language Runtime Execution Engine 2.4 Library)

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ mscorlib.tlb

Add your Code Dom generated Classlibrary to the same directory where the Excel Sheet is stored

3)use the following VBA Code:

```
Sub Command1_Click()
     Dim clr As CorRuntimeHost
     Dim domain As AppDomain
     Dim objTest As Object
     Dim fltResult As String

     Set clr = New CorRuntimeHost

     clr.Start
     clr.GetDefaultDomain domain
     Set objTest = domain.CreateInstanceFrom("C:\Bla\YourGeneratedClassLibrary.dll", "NetComClassLibrary.Info").Unwrap
     fltResult = objTest.Version
     clr.Stop

     '//Debug.Print fltResult
     MsgBox fltResult
 End Sub
```

More infos:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/20/579748.aspx

Comment: this completes my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com

Comment: Okay that looks good. But I won't get Intellisense on objTest, seems like

Comment: Post your NetComClassLibrary.Info or however you renamed it :-)

Comment: I actually don't have one. What/Where is it supposed to come from ?

Comment: You need one, else you need to register your type using regasm. See the  link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com

Comment: Yes the question is how do I get that generated with Codedom now

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [ComVisibleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) it says

> The default is true, which indicates that the managed type is visible to COM. This attribute is not needed to make public managed assemblies and types visible; they are visible to COM by default.

Then there are some restrictions like only public types with default constructor etc.

Comment: Okay then I'm a little puzzled, because if I need to expose C# to VBA by manually building a class project, I need to tick a couple of boxes. And my understanding is that I need a .tlb to be referenced from VBA. I don't seem to be able to produce that at the moment

Comment: Not sure what your mean. You need to register the classes for them to be visible to VBA. Run `regasm /codebase myclasses.dll` (and ignore the warnings about unsigned assemblies)

Comment: I think i do not fully understand com registration, but I guess an answer to the following question will clear things out for me : does that command affect the dll so that it can be distributed to all my clients and used ? Or is it affecting my registry only and all clients will need to register it ?

Comment: VBA looks in the local registry to find available COM objects. i.e. it needs to be registered on each machine where the VBA application runs. I assume it could be distributed via policies but I have not tried it.

Comment: Okay cool. understand all of that. However, registering on each machine is not an option.