# Is there a way for a VB6 application to use newer controls (Like .NET)

Tags: vb6

I like VB.NET, but I can't run the applications anywhere the .NET framework is not installed. Can I make VB6 use the controls that the operating system it runs on uses? I have been searching for this for a while, but with no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you asking?

- If you are asking *whether you need to install the VB6 runtime*: no, [from Windows Vista onwards it is part of Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx), and does not need to be installed. You can even [use registry-free-COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com) to create VB6 applications that use third-party controls but do not need an install package.
- If you are asking *whether it's possible to improve the visual appearance of a VB6 program* so that it looks less old-fashioned, and more like the standard Windows visual styles: yes it is. E.g. use the free add-in [VBAdvance](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/) option "XP Manifest Resource Compiler".

Comment: Yes, I want to make it look not so old-fashoned Thanks

Comment: If the answer helped you, you might like to accept it by ticking the green tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to use some of the newer .NET controls within your VB6 application.

This article might help you -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788241.aspx

It will use the .Net framework that is installed on the machine. You shouldn't have to package any controls up separately.