# Does registration free COM work when the same interface is also registered?

Tags: com, manifest, side-by-side, regsvr32, regfreecom

You can use [registration free COM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/465882/321013) to avoid having to register a COM dll with the registry.

What I'm currently trying to figure out is whether this is still supposed to work when the component you are trying to use is *also* independently registered with the windows registry.

Example:

```
...\MyApp\MyApp.exe
...\MyApp\MyApp.exe.manifest
...\MyApp\pdm.dll <- manifest points to this DLL for ProcessDebugManager Class
```

However, another version of pdm.dll *may* also be registered in the registry by another program.

Which version will MyApp.exe then use? The one from the registry or the one from the program directory referenced in the manifest?

Is this supposed to be supported?

Comment: What happened when you tried?  Manifest were specifically invented to solve the DLL Hell problem caused by the registry.

Comment: The one from the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try it, my private DLL is loaded by the process and not the one registered in the registry. (Verfied through ProcessExplorer)

I still don't *know* whether this is fully supported, but I guess it's good enough.

Comment: How could it *not* be supported?  It has to work.  One of the reasons for reg-free COM is to allow use of a private DLL instead of its public (registered) equivalent with the same typelib, class IDs, etc.  This is what SxS isolation is all about.

Comment: @Bob77 - valid point. The docs for this stuff are so godawful though, I'm not sure I'd take anything for granted in this area.