# Running VB6 applications without installing or registering dlls

Tags: dll, vb6

As at this moment I don't have another PC to test on it, 
Can other users who haven't VB6 on their system (no dlls registered or runtime files) run my application by just including activeX files, DLLs and runtime files into the folder of the application ??? don't DLLs need to be registered ?? If so, is there anyway to register them without doing this by installer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regsvr32 dllname.dll
```

Is the way to register COM dlls.

Comment: Thanks Noodles, I got it now that I can register a component programmatically .. But if the runtime file MSVBVM60.dll is needed so that the application run and dlls registering codes be executed, how the application will run without the MSVBVM60.dll file ?!!

Comment: a/ It's already installed on many modern OSs. b/ See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887/en-au (about latest version) and http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7B9BA261-7A9C-43E7-9117-F673077FFB3C. Note: INF files are installed by `%SystemRoot%\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe "%1"` where %1 is the right clicked inf file.

Comment: The core runtime libraries are included in every version of Windows since Win98SE, and usually it will be present in any Win98 or Win95 system that has ever been updated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use registry-free COM as an alternative to registering components. You supply a "manifest" with your EXE that enables it to find the DLLs and OCXs in the same directory as the EXE. For instance try the tool "[make my manifest](http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/) " which can create a manifest from a VB6 project.

[More details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com)