# Use project dll in client machine without registering .OCX file, ActiveX Dll project

Tags: vb6, side-by-side

I have used VBCCR15.OCX file in my VB6 project in order to get unicode support.

Ours is a **ActiveX Dll project** and we create an executable file to add and register the Project dll file and other related files in client machine at installation time. Now I need to use the project dll without registering the VBCCR15.OCX file in the client machine.

I have tried several ways.

[VBCCR15.OCX thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?841929-VB6-ActiveX-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)) ,I tried this. But it didn't succeeded (The process is for Standard EXE project)

I tried to use Side-by-Side configuration for that. Using [Side by Side Manifest Maker](http://www.mazecomputer.com/), I have created manifest file for the Project.dll file (I added project.dll and VBCCR15.OCX into the Manifest maker and did build). But I don't have any idea about where to add the manifest file.

Do I need to add the manifest file into the VB6 project before create the Project.dll?

Is there any specific way to name the manifest file for 'Project.dll'?

If anybody can, please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I have successfully manifested VBCCR in the past. The tool I've used is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568427/3195477. You should post some more details of what specifically you have done and what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi DaveInCaz,
I have modified the content of my issue now. Actually ours is a ActiveX DLL project ,  I have not clearly mentioned that before. I am sorry for that. All articles I have found so far was for Standard EXE projects.  
I tried with the tool you have mentioned in your comment. It also seems to work with .exe files. 
identity <exe_file> [name] [description]