# VB6 Force application to load local dll over registered one

Tags: dll, com, vb6, manifest, visual-studio-6

my team needs to have the same application deployed in two different folders on the same server but with slightly different code.
We'd like to have a base code on the folder A, and a version with a few changes on the folder B.

I'm trying to understand if this is something we could achieve in VB6 and here's what I'm currently working on.

First, I've created a class project (Project2) with one class in it (Class1.cls):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function WeirdMath(Num1 As Double, Num2 As Double) As Double
    WeirdMath = Num1 + Num2
End Function
```

Then I've created a standard exe project (Project1) which has Project2 as reference.
In the exe project I've created a form with two textboxes, a label and a button.

```
Option Explicit

Private wm As New Class1

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim Num1 As Double
    Dim Num2 As Double

    Num1 = IIf(IsNumeric(Text1.Text), Text1.Text, 0)
    Num2 = IIf(IsNumeric(Text2.Text), Text2.Text, 0)
    Label1.Caption = wm.WeirdMath(Num1 , Num2)
End Sub
```

I've built the two projects in the folder \bin1 and registered the Project2.dll in that folder.
Then I've changed the Class1.cls code to

```
Public Function WeirdMath(Num1 As Double, Num2 As Double) As Double
    WeirdMath = Num1 - Num2
End Function
```

and built the two projects in the \bin2 folder along with this Project1.exe.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Project1" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32"/>
    <file name="Project2.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

I was expecting the **bin1\Project1.exe** to make the sum of two numbers while **bin2\Project1.exe** would be doing the difference.

Does it make any sense? Is it even possible for COM dlls to work this way?

Comment: The manifest is inadequate.  In only states that you have a dependency on project2.dll, it is missing the `comClass` elements that say what COM classes are implemented by project2.  Getting this right for vb6 is not so easy, you need to know the guids.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com).

Comment: That was it. Easier than I thought. I've added this **<comClass progid="Project2.Class1" clsid="{DF4C172F-11E9-4D31-AE1D-6388815B13D2}" description="Class1" />** and it started to work as expected. Thanks a mil!