# How to avoid restarting silent Inno Setup installer without /norestart

Tags: inno-setup

1. I have a **downloader installer** whose function is to download my Inno Setup packaged exe and execute `xxxx.exe /verysilent` for silent installation
2. It has been released for two years and everything is working normally
3. Recently, I upgraded the software package and introduced **COM components in my program**, which may cause system usage issues. So I added `Flags: restartreplace`, and the software will be replaced and upgraded after the next computer restart
4. But! I encountered a big problem. The **download installer** I previously sent to the user is now unable to modify the code. It may appear during the installation and upgrade process, causing the computer to suddenly restart without any prompts!

I found a startup parameter in Inno Setup documentation
`/norestart`, which can install silently without performing a forced restart.

But! My **downloader installer** has been released to many users and cannot be updated, so it cannot add new `/norestart` parameters to launched Inno Setup package.

Is there a solution where I can add some code to the iss script so that if it is silently started, it will automatically add `/norestart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there's an easy solution.

Imo, you have these options (in the order I'd recommend):

1. Implement the replace-on-restart programmatically, using `RestartReplace` function, as shown in my answer to your previous question:
   [How to use flag:restartreplace but without restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77884628/850848)
2. Wrap the installer to yet another application (can be again Inno Setup installer), that adds the `/norestart` command-line parameter.
3. Restart the installer with `/norestart`, when it is started with `/silent`. For an example how to restart installer with different command-line parameters, see for example:
   [Discard the /TYPE and /COMPONENTS parameter on upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45273328/850848)

   This is basically another way to implement the 2. More code, but without need for yet another binary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again. I will try your method. Before that, I plan to clone the source code of Innosetup, then modify it and recompile it